# BST recursive insert - assign new node pointer as leaf's child

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, function-definition

I am trying to implement the insert method for Binary Tree and here is what I have got:

```
struct node * addNode(struct node ** root, struct node * node){
    //base case: when reach leaf
    if (*root == NULL){
        printf("reached with root with node key = %i", node->key);
        return node;
    }
    if ((node -> key) > ((*root)->key)){ //add to the right subtree
        printf("node key is : %i, tree's node key is: %i\n", (node -> key), ((*root)->key));
        (*root)->right = addNode(&((*root)->right), node);
    } else {
        printf("node key is : %i, tree's node key is: %i\n", (node -> key), ((*root)->key));
        (*root)->left = addNode(&((*root)->left), node);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Setting the leaf's child node to the pointer of *node didn't work in this case but I am not sure why. After writing a driver program to tested this method, I got segmentation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is written with the return type struct `node *` then it means that the function has to return pointer to the root node. However if the tree is not empty (that is when the pointer to the root node is not equal to NULL) then the function returns the pointer `node`.

```
struct node * addNode(struct node ** root, struct node * node){
    //...
    return node;
}
```

In this case after calling the function like

```
root = addNode( &root, node );
```

the pointer to the root node will be always equal to the value of `node`.

Also in this case there is no sense to declare the first parameter as having the type struct `node **`.

The function can be written like

```
struct node * addNode( struct node *root, struct node * node )
{
    //base case: when reach leaf
    if ( root == NULL )
    {
        return node;
    }
    else if ( node -> key > root->key )
    {
        root->right = addNode( root->right, node );
        return root;
    } 
    else 
    {
        root->left = addNode( root->left, node );
        return root;
    }
}
```

and called like

```
root = addNode( root, node );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to return `node` after updating `*root` when it is not `NULL`.

You should return `*root` instead not to modify the tree in wrong way.

Comment: But to assign the returned node to (*root)->right or (*root)->left should link the parent node to the child node right? I am not sure why this would be a wrong approach.

Comment: Assigning the pointer to the child node will link the parent node to the child node. `node` is the leaf node to add and it may not be the child node to link.